# intent: URI not working in Android browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

So I'm clicking on this link:

```
<a href="intent://www.google.com#Intent;scheme=http;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end">Google</a>
```

(I know its a silly example, since it could just be http://www.google.com, but its illustrative of the problem)

I determined this URI from

```
Log.v(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")).toUri(
                    Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));
```

I see the following in logcat:

```
08-02 08:32:34.708 I/ActivityManager(   71): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://www.google.com cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity }
08-02 08:32:34.748 E/Tab     ( 4188): onReceivedError -10 intent://www.google.com#Intent;scheme=http;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end The protocol is not supported
```

Rather than redirecting to www.google.com I get the "Web page not available" page.

If I launch the identical intent using the `am` binary, it succeeds.

```
adb -e shell am start -d http://www.google.com -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

I see this in logcat

```
08-02 08:47:42.488 I/ActivityManager(   71): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity }
```

The ultimate goal is to have a URL that launches a specific activity in an app (and theres no way for someone to get to this page without having the app installed).  I know I can also define a custom scheme, but since its a global namespace I'd rather not do that.  I also know I can use http:// for this purpose, but I don't want the user to be prompted whether they want to open the URL in the browser or my app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same problem

Adding the following code to my Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml solved my problem:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```